# Can I distribute a vector in a dot product to another vector dot product?

Tags: vectors, inner-products

Let's say I have a set of vectors $$a, b, c, d$$ that are all n elements.

So if I multiply the dot product of two vectors (one of which is a transpose) I will receive a scalar.

$$(a\cdot b^T)*(c\cdot d^T)=e $$

Where e is a scalar. Also the dot product gives me scalar as well.

In the hw problem I am doing, I know that $$b^T \cdot c$$ would give me a dot product I want that I can move as a scalar to another section of the problem.

So, could $$(a\cdot b^T)*(c\cdot d^T)=(a\cdot d^T)*(c\cdot b^T)$$???

If so, why? Because they are in the same field?

I am tempted to prove it by saying the sum of the elements are all the same:
$$(a\cdot b^T)*(c\cdot d^T)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i*b_i*c_i*d_i$$

Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. Take $a=(1,0)$, $b=(0,1)$, $c=(0,1)$, and $d=(1,0)$. Then$$(a.b^T)\times(c.d^T)=0\text{, but }(a.d^T)\times(c.b^T)=1.$$

Comment: Your $$c \cdot d^T = 0$$ and 1 * 0 = 0.

Comment: Sorry, I mean $$c \cdot b^T $$

Comment: Oh I see what you mean...

Comment: There was a typo and I have fixed it.